# How to exclude folder from ReSharper (javascript) rename refactor (and possible other operations)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am using an ASP MVC project. Both the /Content and the /Script folder has a Kendo subfolder which contains enormous sized files. As a consequence when I am using say a simple ReSharper parameter rename refactor on a controller's action method ReSharper starts to search for minutes in .js files (OK, I understand why), however the Kendo subfolder could be safely skipped.

As a workaround it would be great to exclude the 2 Kendo subfolders from rename refactor, and possibly other operations. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried excluding the files from the solution in Visual Studio? Right-click on the folder/file, choose **Exclude from project**.

Comment: I do not want to exclude it from the solution. It is still content.